# Inputting a tag number in a workbook and pulling row with tag number from various Inventory sheets, deleting them, &inserting row into a Sold sheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I’m currently trying to write a program that allows me to streamline my sales auditing.

My task involves inputting a tag number for a sold item, locating the item and all of its details in a workbook in various Inventory sheets (there are five total currently with some inventory overlap, eventually they’ll be shrunk down to one or two), removing them completely from the Inventory sheets, and adding the item details to a Sold sheet. Is there a way I can automate this using Excel or Google Sheets? I have an idea on how to utilize Python with it but I want to see if I can use equations in Excel or Sheets first.

I’ve found some success in being able to pull the item details from a different sheet using Xlookup for individual Inventory sheets, but when I try to nest if statements so it can check through all of the Inventory sheets, it doesn’t work out. Furthermore, I don’t know how to account for duplicated tag numbers (ex. if the tag number I want to input is 123456, and there are multiple items in the specific inventory sheet with the tag number, I’m not sure how to only delete the first row containing the tag number and not the others). This is what I have.

```
=ifs( A1 = vlookup(A1, Incoming!$G:$G,1, FALSE), xlookup(A1, Incoming!$G:$G, Incoming!$A:$P), A1 = vlookup(A1, AUDIT_7.20.22!$G:$G, 1, FALSE), xlookup(A1, AUDIT_7.20.22!$G:$G, AUDIT_7.20.22!$A:$P), A1 = vlookup(A1, AUDIT_SHEET_BIG_HAMMAL!$G:$G, 1, FALSE), xlookup(A1, AUDIT_SHEET_BIG_HAMMAL!$G:$G, AUDIT_SHEET_BIG_HAMMAL!$A:$P), A1 = vlookup(RECEIVING_MOVE!$G:$G, 1, FALSE), xlookup(A1, RECEIVING_MOVE!$G:$G, RECEIVING_MOVE!$A:$P), A1 = vlookup(A1, OLD_WAREHOUSE!$G:$G, 1, FALSE), xlookup(A1, OLD_WAREHOUSE!$G:$G, OLD_WAREHOUSE!$A:$P) )
```

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.